# What is the synonym/antonym for "feminist"/"feminism"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrase-requests, antonyms

I am looking for a word or phrase that are to men's rights as the words *feminist/feminism* are to women rights.

And will the word or phrase be called a synonym or antonym?

Comment: See [Men’s Rights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men's_rights).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Etymologically "Feminism" is derived from "female" and historically it has referred to women's rights. But the term — as a sociological term as well as a social movement — has evolved in many ways, so while for some "feminism" is the struggle for women's rights in society, others will explain that feminism is the struggle to remove gender-biases from society, and as such applies to men's rights as well as women's.

So when you're looking for the complementary term to feminism, you need to know exactly which meaning of feminism you're going for, because in many contexts "feminism" might be enough for you.

Also, it should be noted that even if we find a term that says "mens' rights" to complement feminism as womens' rights, they will never be entirely parallel in tone and connotation, because mens' rights and women's rights aren't symmetrical. If (some versions of) feminism describes itself as the struggle to achieve equal rights in a male-dominated world, a totally equivalent term would have to imply a similar male struggle, which is, well, a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I agree with your explanation as to why we don't have an equivalent   
word that says mens' rights. 
Thanks for answering query :)

Comment: What about *gender equality* to empahsize equal rights for all?

Answer (score 8):

There is an ostensible but in the end untenable male counterpart to feminism, namely

> [Masculinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculinism)

but because of the long history of feminism and the much shorter and shallower history of masculinism, and fairly different agendas, it'd be difficult to call them perfect pairs.

The suggestion of this word is only to express that in at least one direction there is a corresponding term for males that is superficially appropriate.

Feminism is (terribly oversimplified) a movement that is directed towards equalizing the power and rights of women to that of men, given that they are almost universally allowed little power and few rights. *Masculinism* is not the same concept replacing 'women' with 'men', rather it is more of an intellectual reaction to feminism, trying to increase awareness of where feminism has restricted the rights of males. There is a perception by some that power and rights is a zero-sum game and that gains by one is a loss by the other.

Though this theoretically might be the case, the surface meaning of *masculinism* might lead one to use it as a counterpart to feminism, the term seems closer in practice to reactive male chauvinism and misogyny.

Comment: There is a men's movement, that unlike misogyny or men's rights, is actually not anti-feminist, just emphasizing, with respect to feminism, the positive aspects of masculinity.

Comment: Kind of failed to read the linked article, eh. It identifies *masculism* as a counterpart to *feminism* and *mascul-in-ism* as antifeminist. The OP wants the former.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t believe that there is a direct masculine equivalent for feminist, because it’s a fight for the rights of a discriminated group and this is not the case of men.

But if it helps you, there is a generic word for those who oppose any kind of gender discrimination: ***anti-sexist***.

Answer (score 4):

For what its worth, *feminism* is the promotion of women and women’s rights. This is inconsistent with the promotion of **equal** rights.

*Women’s Liberation* is more in keeping with promoting equality.

Answer (score 0):

While this might be too basic and directly answerable a question for this venue, you might be looking for [misogynist/misogyny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misogyny). It has a different connotation, but there haven't been enough English-speaking, female-dominated societies for us to have come up with a positive word for it.

Comment: Misogyny is the opposite of feminism, holding the opposite sentiment towards women and their standing, not a parallel, holding the same sentiment towards men as feminism towards women.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any English-speaking countries with significant male-rights issues, so this was the closest I could come up with. Having grown up with _rabid_, _fringe_ feminists, forgive me if I made the association too easily.

Comment: @StoneyB - misogyny is surely opposite to feminism.

Comment: aLearner, it may not be a mirror image or male analog, though, which is more of what @StoneyB was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Feminism introduces a *political*/social *idea* and it is not an adjective that has an antonym. It is not like white/black or negative/positive. If you insist on finding an antonym conveying a positive meaning you are beating the air because this *idea* is a reaction against an universal negative action called *sexism* so its antonym cannot be positive. As others have mentioned before and I agree with, you can use *misogyny*.

About synonym, there is no synonym and cannot be because with changing the name you will find something else instead of *feminism* like "women's liberation" or "women's rights", none of which can include the whole issue feminism wants to talk about and has been created because of.

Some of opportunists and beneficiaries are trying to change the name to change the meaning and reduce it from a strong and wave maker movement to a weak and sentimental idea holding nothing unless forgetting what Feminism is and why it has been created and we need it like our need to freedom of expression and democracy. There is only one way to scape of it by not calling yourself a feminist and ignore it if you (I do not mean personal) do not like it but no way to force the others ignore a brilliant history behind this word which is continuing in the world like *fighting against racism*. No one can delete a part of history which is still continuing.

Comment: +1, and +10 if I could. This is the only answer that makes sense here.

Answer (score -3):

From Mexican Spanish, you have **machismo**.

> Machismo
>
> 1. A strong or exaggerated sense of masculinity stressing attributes such as physical courage, virility, domination of women, and
>      aggressiveness.

This question would have no sense in Spanish. Even a child would tell you that the opposite of *feminismo* is *machismo*.

Comment: *Feminismo* and *machismo* are not opposites in Spanish. Not even close.